# Suspicious Login Success in Event Viewer

Tags: security, login, remote-access, eventviewer

Hope you can help.  We have been noticing another user's local machine creating logon entries in the event viewer of our machine.

The message received is "An account was successfully logged on".

The details of the logon attempt are provided below (anonymized):

```
Subject:
Security ID:        NULL SID
Account Name:       -
Account Domain:     -
Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

New Logon:
Security ID:        OURDOMAN\SUSPICIOUSID$
Account Name:       SUSPICIOUSID$
Account Domain:     OURDOMAIN
Logon ID:       0x8276c3c
Logon GUID:     {ef03e93f-a27b-c304-92ce-3b244723ccc4}

Process Information:
Process ID:     0x0
Process Name:       -

Network Information:
Workstation Name:   
Source Network Address: IPAddress1
Source Port:        55666
```

I have tried to pick this up using a batch script and psfile, but it is not picking up anything around the time of the logon event.  It does pick up if someone else remotes as admin on when we test it.

BAtch file script:

```
:Start
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set theValue=x
cd c:/pstools
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('psfile.exe \\MyMachine') do @set theValue=!theValue! %%a
IF not "%theValue%"=="x No files opened remotely on MyMachine." ( echo    %theValue%>>c:/psfileoutput/psfileoutput.txt ) else ( echo "no values" )
timeout 0
```

Goto Start

I would have thought that a logon success would result in some sort of file access.

Does anyone have any ideas of what this logon could be?

Thanks

UPDATE:

UPDATE: Finally got a hit with my batch script:

```
   x Files opened remotely on MyMachine: [183] \srvsvc User: SuspiciousID$ Locks: 0  Access: Read Write
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication and authorization are two different concepts. The first is basically verifying logon credentials, while the second is checking what kind of access the user is entitled to.

`\srvsvc` is not a file, it is a so-called "named pipe" and mainly used as a mechanism to enumerate the shares provided by a file server - which is what is being done when a file server is called in Windows Explorer (i.e. you enter `\\server` in the address bar) or upon a `net view \\server` request. As your machine account *SUSPICIOUSID$* is member of the *AUTHENTICATED USERS* builtin group, it is entitled to use `\srvsvc` by default to list shares on all domain members. It does not mean that it can access any of the listed shares or the files therein.

Answer (score 0):

Logon success by no means guarantees file access, a simple connection to admin$ will show as a logon event but makes no file level changes.

Its difficult to say what your issue is here, a quick google of the port listed shows a number of sites listing a trojan named Latinus that has been seen to be using this port quite recently. I'd personally check the other machine any infections.

http://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=55666

If you have access to the other machine, have a look at the application or security event logs at the same times that you are seeing the events on your own machine. you may see more information about what process is making the attempts to connect out.

Comment: Thanks - we don't currently have access to the other machine -  we're really just hoping to find out what is going on before we wade in.  UPDATE:

UPDATE:
Finally got a hit with my batch script:

x Files opened remotely on MyMachine: [183] \srvsvc     User:   SuspiciousID$     Locks:  0     Access: Read Write